# Use link to page from structure in Liferay ADT

Tags: liferay, freemarker

I have created structure with field "Link to page".

Now I want to display the link in ADT applied to content aggregator. How do I obtain the URL of the linked page?

I tried this approach, but it returns only some encoded-hash-something from the webcontent.

```
<#assign
    docXml = saxReaderUtil.read(curEntry.getAssetRenderer().getArticle().getContent())
    page_link = docXml.valueOf("//dynamic-element[@name='page_link']/dynamic-content/text()")
>

<a href="${page_link}">link to page</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

What kind of content you are working with? Web content or dynamic data lists?

If you have a web content structure with a link to page field and want to show it in a web content template use this to access the URL

```
<a href="${LinkToPage.getFriendlyUrl()}">...</a>
```

If you want to access DDM fields in ADT try this

```
<#assign fields = storageEngine.getFields(DDMStorageId) />
<#assign contentLink = ddmUtil.getDisplayFieldValue(themeDisplay, fields.get("LinkToPage").getValue(), "ddm-link-to-page") />
```

Comment: Web content. If i use it in template, i can use `page_link.getFriendlyUrl()`, but in ADT I can't. I will try the DDM fields then.

Comment: Web content? Web content display portlet does not support ADT. Haven't you rather created a Dynamic Data List (not a Web content structure) with a link to page field and that you want to display with the use of ADT?

Comment: I want to use it as webcontent displayed by asset publisher and ADT.